# lldb breakpoint, loaded nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller, lldb

I have an app with no nibs. Its rootviewcontroller is a tableviewcontroller. I am having it push to a second tableviewcontroller, which controls a detailview. Just earlier this week, I had it successfully pushing to the next tableviewcontroller. A few days later (and after maybe saving the wrong version),

I get an

**(lldb)** with a breakpoint at the pushViewController method when I select a table item.  I have breakpoints for all exceptions enabled. If I press the play button twice more, I get this in my output box:

" **** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "TopicsDetailViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"**

Is there something wrong here or do I need to look elsewhere in my project?

This is in my header interface:

```
    TopicsDetailViewController *tdvController;
```

: ) And this is my didSelectRowAt...

```
       tdvController = [[TopicsDetailViewController alloc] init];

             tdvController.aFeed = afeed;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tdvController animated:YES];
    tdvController = nil;
```

Thank you, and let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's a different var as far as I can see, has an extra 'c'

Comment: Thank you! That had been itching me for a while.

Comment: Sorry Valentin, updated it.

Comment: Then @h2co3 got the right guess, that makes sense, accordingly with the warnning you got. Not sure why he deleted his comment tho.

Comment: The main problem remains: it breaks when I want to load my next viewcontroller...

Comment: do you add a view to your tdvcontroller in 'loadView' ?

Comment: ...  Stay tuned for my next bumbling foible... Thank you Valentin for your acute observation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, your tdvController declaration in the interface file is named the same as the tdvController in the instance method where you are getting the exception.

If your intentions are to create and use the instance variable in this instance method don't declare it again, just do:

self.tdvcController = [[TopicsDetailViewController alloc] init];

Which is creating the object on the heap.

If you intentions are to use a local variable of type TopicsDetailViewController in this instance method that is not the iVar, then rename the local variable to something else.

Comment: That was answered in a comment above, so now the issue is why it breaks and considering the output message.